# Java.Lang.StackoverflowError при отправке пуш-уведомления

Tags: android, retrofit2, push-уведомления

Прошу помощи. Сам не программист, просто пытаюсь написать приложение для своего маленького стартапа. при нажатии на кнопку приложение меняет данные в firebase realtime database и отправляет пуш-уведомление на другой телефон/приложение. На каких-то телефонах работает как надо, а на каких-то вылетает. Java.Lang.StackoverflowError. Думаю проблема либо в retrofit, либо в корутинах.

Интерфейс ретрофит с корутинами. Если закоментировать @Headers или @POST приложение не вылетает, но и пуш естественно не отправляется.

```
    interface NotificationAPI {

    @Headers("Authorization:  key=$SERVER_KEY", "Content-Type:$CONTENT_TYPE")
    @POST("fcm/send")
    suspend fun postNotification(
        @Body notification: PushNotification
    ): Response<ResponseBody>}
```

Код из активити с кнопкой.

```
    override fun onNeSdelanoClick(work: SmetaFB) {
        if (work.executor == execName) {
            myRef.child(selectedCategory).child(work.id!!).child("executor").removeValue()
            myRef.child(selectedCategory).child(work.id!!).child("sdelanoDate").removeValue()
            myRef.child(selectedCategory).child(work.id!!).child("ogidaetRascheta").setValue(false)


            val title = projName
            val message = "$execName - Не сделал - ${work.workName} - в $roomName"
            if (title.isNotEmpty() && message.isNotEmpty()) {
                PushNotification(
                    Message(
                        title,
                        message,
                        projId,
                        roomId,
                        roomName,
                        selectedCategory,
                        work.workName!!
                    ),
                    TOPIC_WORK
                ).also {
                    sendNotification(it)
                }
            }
        } else Toast.makeText(
            this, " Выполнил ${work.executor}. " +
                    "Обратитесь к руководителю.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }


    private fun sendNotification(notification: PushNotification) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
            try {
                val response = RetrofitInstance.api.postNotification(notification)
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response: ${Gson().toJson(response)}")
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, response.errorBody().toString())
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
            }
        }
```

Ещё код от ретрофита.

```
 class RetrofitInstance {

    companion object {
        private val retrofit by lazy {
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }

        val api by lazy {
            retrofit.create(NotificationAPI::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

FireBase service.

```
private const val CHANNEL_ID = "WorkChanged"
private const val OTCHET_ID = "otchet"
class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    companion object {
        var sharedPref: SharedPreferences? = null

        var token: String?
            get() {
                return sharedPref?.getString("token", "")
            }
            set(value) {
                sharedPref?.edit()?.putString("token", value)?.apply()
            }
    }

    override fun onNewToken(newToken: String) {
        super.onNewToken(newToken)
        token = newToken
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val notificationID = Random.nextInt()

        createNotificationChannelWork(notificationManager)

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            FLAG_ONE_SHOT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(message.data["title"])
            .setContentText(message.data["message"])
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.mipmap.sym_def_app_icon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification)
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannelWork(notificationManager: NotificationManager) {
        val channelName = "Изменение в работах"
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, IMPORTANCE_HIGH).apply {
            description = ""
            enableLights(true)
            lightColor = Color.GREEN
        }
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

}
```

Манифест.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/vaex_icon_blue"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/vaex_icon_blue"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.VaexExecutor"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ToolsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".notification.FirebaseService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Помогите чем сможете. Или тыкнете носом как можно реализовать пуши иначе, без ретрофита и корутин.

Comment: Так вы саму ошибку приведите, никто ваш код запускать не будет. Без нее не о чем разговаривать.